# Session not available in Ajax, but in the regular PHP-script

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am currently writing an ajax-application, which gets some of its config-params by sessions.

The session['apps']['appXY'], which is holding these params, is built in the php-script, which provides the js-links, calling the ajax. As i dont want the sessions['apps']['appXY'] consume resources, when the user doesnt use the ajax-app, i have the session['apps'] array deleted each time, the user calls any site by regular/synchron way.

The order of the site-buildup is like this:

- session['apps'] is deleted;
- app-classes are included
- within each app (f.e. appXY), if needed for ajax, the session['apps']['appXY'] is built (Step3)
- site is built, loading is complete, user is calling some ajax-functionality, which may depend on the session['apps']['appXY']

The Problem with this now, if at the beginning of the sites building process the session['apps'] is deleted, that the session-array $session['apps']['appXY'] is not available within the ajax-script anymore, even though, it was rebuilt - and is existing and usable - in step3, the regular php-script of appXY.

If i dont delete the session its available by ajax too, but i dont understand, why is the session not available in the ajax-application, as the deleting of it is before the rebuilding? What could cause the fact, that session is available in regular php-script, but not in ajax, after deleting and rebuilding it?

Thanx, Jayden

Comment: What resources are you talking about? Unless you're stuffing a few mega-/giga-bytes of data into the session in those apps sub-arrays, there is very little 'overhead' except some extra disc usage... and disc space is very cheap these days.

Comment: @Marc B The array-key for on extension f.e. $session['apps']['appXY'] could contain up to 50 keys itself. I actually thought that would be a lot, at least, to carry it along on each site, even if you dont need them anymore. better to delete it, no?

Comment: @Ninsuo yes, i could put the relevant parts together, its from several files...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ninsuo, i try to make the szenario more clearly by a more detailed model, containing some code:

In the main-class, before including any of the modules (apps) all ajax-sessions are deleted:

```
function get-apps()
{
    unset($_SESSION['ajaxconf']);

    require_once(appXY.php);
    require_once(appABC.php);
}
```

Then, in class 'appXY.php' the session '$_SESSION['ajaxconf']['appXY']' is (re)filled:

```
class appXY extends base
{
    function main ( $localconf, $lang ) 
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        $_SESSION['ajaxconf']['appXY'][$key] = $value;

        return '<a href="index.php?id=123&param1=234" onclick="ajax-app(234) return false;">click</a>
    }
}
```

Getting the values from '$_SESSION['ajaxconf']['appXY']' works fine in the ajax-script, which is called by the javascript-function 'ajax-app()', as long as the the session is not deleted at the beginnning of the php function 'get-apps()'. If the session is deleted though, its not available in the ajax-file, even though, it has been redefined again in the class 'appXY', which clearly is included after deleting the sessions. to me, this doesnt make much sense, as the session is available in the class 'appXY'.